# React Native Swift Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, react-native

I have an error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.  I am unsure how to fix this error.

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  var bridge: RCTBridge!

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let jsCodeLocation: URL

    #if DEBUG
      jsCodeLocation = URL(string: "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios")
    #else
      jsCodeLocation = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main", withExtension: "jsbundle")!
    #endif
    let rootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleName: "MyReactSwift", initialProperties: nil, launchOptions: launchOptions)
    let rootViewController = UIViewController()
    rootViewController.view = rootView

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The "!" forces the unwrapping which means it crash if there is no value. In your case there is no resource "main" with extension jsbundle.

Comment: fixed issue by adding main.jsbundle but it seem as it is running off of the main.jsbundle instead of metro bundler. Seem as #if DEBUG is working backwards